# Android Application dosent work on release mode on device with api 21&22

Tags: android, api, build

For some reason my application dosent work in release mode (in debug mode everything is fine) on devices with api 21&22
 when i am trying to lounch the app i am getting this error

```
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.MyApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.MyApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
                                                 at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:566)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4534)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1346)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5291)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
```

Comment: Check the manifest and `<application/>` tag, see is the package name of your `Application` class correct and did you pass correct `Application` class

Answer (score 0):

Try this: use the same version android support library in your project and library projects you included.

After Clean and Rebuild.